# Reading Data Sets from XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

I have a simple class I am designing to log messages on a hosted website.

To store the messages, I have created this simple class structure:

```
public class StoredMsg {
  public StoredMsg() {
  }
  public string From { get; set; }
  public string Date { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

These messages will be written and read back using a `StoredMessages : List<StoredMsg>` class.

This is the original format of the `Read` method:

```
  public void Read() {
    //string xmlPath = WebPage.Server.MapPath(XML_PATH);
    if (File.Exists(xmlPath)) {
      using (var xr = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath)) {
        StoredMsg item = null;
        while (xr.Read()) {
          if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
            if (xr.Name == HEAD) {
              if (item != null) {
                this.Add(item);
              }
              item = new StoredMsg();
            } else if (xr.Name == FROM) {
              item.From = xr.ReadElementString();
            } else if (xr.Name == DATE) {
              item.Date = xr.ReadElementString();
            } else if (xr.Name == MESSAGE) {
              item.Message = xr.ReadElementString();
            }
          }
        }
        xr.Close();
      }
    }
  }
```

The `Write` method was originally in this format:

```
  public void Write(StoredMsg item) {
    using (var stream = File.Open(xmlPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)) {
      using (var xw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
        xw.WriteStartElement(HEAD);
        {
          xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n\t");
          xw.WriteElementString(FROM, item.From);
          xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n\t");
          xw.WriteElementString(DATE, item.Date);
          xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n\t");
          xw.WriteElementString(MESSAGE, item.Message);
          xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        }
        xw.WriteEndElement();
        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
      }
      stream.Close();
    }
  }
```

The problem was that the `Read` method did not like something in the structure of my XML, so my list was always empty.

It is hard to troubleshoot this on a hosted website, so I started looking online at examples to see what I might have been doing wrong.

During my search, I found [Microsoft's How to: Write Object Data to an XML File (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172873.aspx) which showed me a simple way to streamline what my `Write` method had done:

```
private XmlSerializer serializer;

public StoredMessages() {
  serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StoredMsg));
}

public void Write(StoredMsg item) {
  using (var file = new StreamWriter(xmlPath, true)) {
    serializer.Serialize(file, item);
  }
}
```

That, to me, is simplicity and elegance!

Being happy with this, I went on to [Microsoft's How to: Read Object Data from an XML File (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172872.aspx), so I could implement it as well.

### Here is the problem:

The best I can seem to do is write my method like this:

```
public void Read() {
  if (File.Exists(xmlPath)) {
    using (var file = new StreamReader(xmlPath)) {
      // How do I handle multiple nodes?
      // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172872.aspx
      var item = (StoredMsg)serializer.Deserialize(file);
      this.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
```

I am very interested in seeing someone show me how to read all of my items in Linq to XML and I will give a +1 for that, but the question here is how I would read all of my data in using this `Read` technique above.

Is it that I am incorrectly casting the deserialized object to a `StoredMsg` instead of something else? If so, what would the **something else** be?

- `StoredMsg[]`?
- `List<object>`?
- `StoredMessages`?

Thanks for reading all of this, and I hope my code is legible to others.

Example data provided as a screenshot to prevent others from grabbing my email address too easily:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a sample xml document?

Comment: One record of example data has been posted. So far, that's all I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is more generic way, No you can pass any object to Read/Write

```
void Write<T>(Stream s,T obj)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(s, obj);
}

T Read<T>(Stream s)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(s);
}
```

For example

```
StoredMsg[] msgs = .....;
Write(stream, msgs);
```

or

```
StoredMsg[] msgs = Read<StoredMsg[]>(stream());
```

---

**EDIT**

```
void Write<T>(string fileName, T obj)
{
    using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        Write(stream, obj);
    }
}

T Read<T>(string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        return Read<T>(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... well, yeah. That's basically what MS's website has. But I am writing **ONE** element (as someone posts a comment on a website) and I need to read back **ALL** elements. How do I take your `Read` method and convert that to all elements?

Comment: Ah! I see the edit. So, if I write one element as an array of 1 items, will this blow away all of the existing data?

Comment: @jp2code your xml will contain *one* type of data. write single element/read single element. Or write array/read array.

Comment: I like this, but I need to create a different XML file to write this differently structured data to. That's OK. Any idea how to create or initialize the XML file to use the structure similar to what [DGibbs] has posted in his answer?

Comment: @jp2code how about creating an array with 1 element and `Write`ing it.

Comment: I still don't understand how to create a compatible `Stream` if the file does not yet exist. I tried `XmlWriter.Create(File.Create(xmlPath), objSettings)`, but then my localhost website crashed with **XmlException** `Root element is missing` error.

Comment: @jp2code it can be a simple `FileStream`. `File.Open` or `File.Create` will work. For example **using (var stream = File.Create(@"e:\temp\a.xml"))
            {
                Write(stream, new StoredMsg{From="f",Date="1/1/2011",Message="test"});
            }**

Comment: @jp2code and **using (var stream = File.Open(@"e:\temp\a.xml",FileMode.Open))
            {
                var msg  = Read<StoredMsg>(stream);
            }**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a similar XML structure:

```
<Messages>
  <MessageHead>
    <From>Stackoverflow</From>
    <Date>09/05/2013</Date>
    <Message>Hello world</Message>
  </MessageHead>
  <MessageHead>
    <From>Stackoverflow</From>
    <Date>09/05/2013</Date>
    <Message>Second Message</Message>
  </MessageHead>
</Messages>
```

You could use a LINQ to XML query to read each of the `MessageHead` sub nodes as a single message:

```
var nodes = (from n in xml.Descendants("MessageHead")
             select new
             {
                 From = (string)n.Element("From").Value,
                 Date = (string)n.Element("Date").Value,
                 Message = (string)n.Element("Message").Value
             }).ToList();
```

This gives a list of two nodes containing:

- From
- Date
- Message

From there it's very easy to map them to your class, e.g.

```
foreach (var n in nodes)
{
     StoredMessage s = new StoredMessage();
     s.from = n.From;
     s.date = n.Date;
     s.message = n.Message;
}
```

Comment: `xml` could be an XDocument e.g. `XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("xml file");`.